# How to better refactor loops in procedural world generation?

Tags: 2d, procedural-generation, data-structure

One of the steps for cell-based dungeon generation is deciding the amount and location of exits for each room. My current set up consists of the following:

1. Define my exits. There are 15 types of room exits:

   - Left (L), Right (R), Top (T), Bottom (B).
   - Every non-redundant combinatoric of two directions (LT, TR, RB, BL, LR, TB)
   - The same for three directions (LTR, TRB, RBL, BLT)
   - All directions (LRTB)
2. Create a list `exitsList` that contains the type of exit of that index, i.e. `exitsList[0] = L` means that our first room has a single exit: one to the left.

After creating my basic level layout and having my exit generation ready, it's time to go back to each room and assign its exits, and **this** is the part I'm having my doubts about.

Currently, my method for assigning rooms is to make a case check looping through each cell. Something such as:

```
for (each room){
    switch (exitsList[this_room]) {
        case L:
            place_exit_L;
            break;
        case LT:
            place_exit_L;
            place_exit_T;
            break;
        case TR:
        .
        .
        .
        case LTRB:
            place_exit_L;
            place_exit_T;
            place_exit_R;
            place_exit_B;
            break;
        default:
            return_error;
            break;
    }
}
```

While this can work, it seems very inelegant, and more importantly obnoxious to read by a human. I was able to refactor cases that shared the same type of exit by omitting breaks, for example:

```
case LTR:
    place_exit_R;
case LT
    place_exit_T;
case L
    place_exit_L;
    break;
```

But this seems rather arbitrary. I suspect there's a more efficient way to do this, or at least one that won't become a pain to read by other people if the number of exits somehow increases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use four attributes instead of one for expressing the types of exits for a room.

```
for (each room){
    if (room.has_left_exit){
        place_exit_L;
    }
    if (room.has_top_exit){
        place_exit_T;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Building on the answer from @congusbonus, if you are committed to using a single variable in an array as you have shown, you can define each combination in such a way that encodes each direction as a single bit in a bitmask:

```
int T = 1;
int L = 2;
int B = 4;
int R = 8:

int TL = T | L;
...

for (each room){
    int exits = exitsList[this_room];
    if (exits & L == L){
        place_exit_L;
    }
    if (exits & T == T){
        place_exit_T;
    }
    if (exits & B == B){
        place_exit_B;
    }
    if (exits & R == R){
        place_exit_R;
    }
}
```